# Run Rust program without cargo run

Tags: rust, command-line-interface

I built a simple CLI written in Rust that executes with the command `cargo run <ARGUMENTS>`. I want to be able to run the CLI from any directory. I used the clap crate and want to be able to call the script with the name passed to clap: `brainfast <ARGUMENTS>`. I am running on macOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more like a generic question (and I think a duplicate too, but I can't find any).

You have to copy your executable that is generated by `cargo build --release` (you can find it in `target/release/`*`crate_name`*) to a folder in your `$PATH`.

I'm not an expert in macOS, so I can't tell you what is a folder that is included in the `$PATH`, but you can find that out by yourself by opening a terminal and typing `echo $PATH`. Use one of the paths and it should be available in your terminal without cargo or using any path.

As an alternative, you can add a folder to your `$PATH` variable and put it there, e.g.

```
export PATH /home/foobar/.bin:$PATH
cp target/release/brainfast /home/foobar/.bin
brainfast abc.txt 1 3 99 u
```

Comment: It's not the best idea to set any random folder to your $PATH (some malicious app could take advantage of it).

Comment: Can you name an example? You can always use a full path as a malicious app, so why rely on $PATH?

Comment: @hellow Security issues arise if the directory (or any parent) is writable by a different user than the user who adds it to their path. It's easier to keep track of permissions if you limit yourself to a few dedicated directories for this.