# Why does 'cargo run' work but running executable directly fails to load shared libraries?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, onnx, onnxruntime

I can compile and run my Rust project without any problems using `cargo run --release`. As a second step I simply want to create the binary using `cargo build --release` and then executing it by running `./target/release/crate_name` (it is also explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51779809/run-rust-program-without-cargo-run)). Executing the binary results in the behaviour that some shared libraries are not found. This is my `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[package]
name = "onnx-test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2023"

[dependencies]
actix-web = "4"
futures = "0.3.26"
serde = { version = "1", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1"
onnxruntime = "0.0.14"
image = "0.24.5"
imageproc = "0.23.0"
rusttype = "0.9.3"
lazy_static = "1.4.0"
base64 = "0.21.0"
actix-cors = "0.6.4"
derive_more = "0.99.17"
actix-web-validator = "5.0.1"
validator = { version = "0.16", features = ["derive"] }
regex = "1.5.6"
```

And this is the error message:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libonnxruntime.so.1.8.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So my question, is `cargo run --release` linking some libraries implicitly? I mean the library exisits somewhere in the `target/release/build/...` path. I did not found out anything by providing the `--verbose` flag.

Here are the contents of `target/release`:

```
build/
deps/
examples/
incremental/
onnx-test
onnx-test.d
```

Comment: Probably a case of adjusting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for you.

Comment: Provide the output of `ls target/release`

Comment: @tadman I thought about that, but the libraries are not in one folder, they are all in subfolders and I don't want to adjust the path for each library?

Comment: @PitaJ I added the output as edit in the question.

Comment: We might have to reproduce this error on our own machine. Please [edit] your question to provide a full [MRE], including everything necessary to create the error on our own machines. Meaning: a `main.rs`, the `Cargo.toml`(which you already provided), and instructions on how you installed the library in question, in case you installed it manually somewhere. Also, please try to reduce the problem down to a minimal example, including only the dependencies in your `Cargo.toml` that are necessary.

Comment: This is the problem that [`cargo install`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-install.html) solves. When in the `target` directory they're not fully installed, so there may be some overhead in getting it to run from there if avoiding `cargo run`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The behavior is [documented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html#dynamic-library-paths).

> Cargo also sets the dynamic library path when compiling and running binaries with commands like `cargo run` and `cargo test`. This helps with locating shared libraries that are part of the build process.

And [here is the current implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/2cf2c32c1a3dd1843374d28b89c775b3ba9de042/src/cargo/core/compiler/compilation.rs#L262-L297).